# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'jobArray' of 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.state' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been working on a job site for a few weeks. I am still pretty new to React. Every page is working perfectly (signin, signup etc) except this one for displaying jobs. The error I get when compiling is the title of this question. Also, the console logs aren't working at all.

I've tried everything like adding hard-coded data as you can see, but nothing works. The back-end code is working fine.

```
const token = getCookie('token');
const jobArray = ["dalas nalgas"];

class JobListClass extends React.Component {

  state = { jobArray };

  componentDidMount() {
    !isAuth()? navigator.goTo("/") : this.load();
  }

  load = async () => {
    try {
      const response = axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: process.env.REACT_APP_API+'/jobs'
      })
      console.log("response data:"+response.data);
      this.setValues({jobArray : response.data});
      //console.log("jobarray with data:" +jobArray);
    }
    catch(err) {
      toast.error("No info has been retrieved.");
    }
  };

    listJobs = () => {
        const {jobArray} = state;
        console.log("array:"+jobArray);
            const array = jobArray.map((job, index) => {
        return (
        <div key={index}>
            <h5 className="card-title">{ job.enterprise_name }</h5>
            <p className="card-text">{ job.pos }</p>
            <p className="card-text">{ job.desc }</p>
            <p className="card-text">{ job.salary } USD per week.</p>
            <p className="card-text">{ job.hours } per day.</p>                    

            { isAuth() && isAuth().role === 'admin' ?
            <div>
                <Link to={"jobs/update/" + job._id} className="btn btn-primary">Update</Link>
                <button onClick={ this.showDetails }>Show</button>
            </div>
            : null }
        </div>
    )
    });
    return array;
  };
```

Comment: Please clarify what exactly is not working: which error you get, what fails, what is the behaviour you expected and the result you're getting instead of it.

Comment: The jobArray is not working. It is always undefined despite I hard-coded a text and React still can't map the array. jobArray is supposed to save the response.data obtained from the API/jobs url. It contains enterprise_name, position, description, hours and salary.

I am supposed to store that response.data and then use that data to display it in a list, and then from that list, from the ID, obtain the data of that single job and display it using a modal. I was going to post the whole code but Stackoverflow didn't let me do it

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'll make easy for you to make this work.

First is why did you define `jobArray` as const on the top. Const is const. Their values cannot change once they define. And in the middle of code also you make state variable as the same const. So how react is going to find which one is it should destructure.

Since React is the library I cannot say do this in this and this way. But you have to follow best practices. Rather than keep the state in classes it's good to keep it inside constructor like this. If you are new to programming do a search on what is the constructor and why we're using it.

Again back to answer you can do this,

```
constrcutor(){
 super();
 this.state={
  jobArray:[]
 }
}
```

There after you have to bind data retrieving method inside constructor.
So then you can destructure jobArray as you did `const {jobArray} = state;`
When you are generating JSX template inside listJobs() method you didn't handle situations where handling empty array. To do that you can replace like this,

```
const array = jobArray|| jobArray.map((job, index) => {
```

And I couldn't see where are you rendering your all JSX templates and how it's going to return. So look into that as well. Normally if it is a class-based UI component it should have to render() method and inside its return where you return JSX. Complete that part and make sure to export your class component. So you can use it without any problems.

Comment: Hello and thank you so much for answering. Answering your question on why I used const... basically I've watched a tutorial and this guy used const when defining variables so I got the idea on that's what to use.. I commented the definition of `const jobArray` at the top and `state = {jobArray}`.
I've used the constructor and the problem is still there. What am I missing? by the way, I call the listJobs method inside the `render()`method as `this.listJobs()`I don't know if that could be causing some noise? probably not.

Comment: Urgh, I am sorry to say that the question author's account is already deleted, some three hours after posting the question. I don't know why.